# tshark do not assembly TCP fragments into large packets

Tags: csv, tcp, tls1.2, tshark

I have a simple pcap with some web traffic and am using tshark to obtain some header information from it:

I use the following command:

```sh
tshark -r ./capture-1-5 -Y "http2" -o tls.keylog_file:ssl-key.log \
-T fields -e frame.number -e _ws.col.Time -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport \
-e ip.dst  -e tcp.dstport -e _ws.col.Protocol -e frame.len \
-e _ws.col.Info -E header=y -E separator="," -E quote=d \ 
-E occurrence=f > desegmented.csv
```

I realized that in this case all fragments are reassembled resulting in huge packets. However, I do not want reassembled packets. So, I add an extra option to tshark:

```sh
tshark -r ./capture-1-5 -Y "http2" -o tls.keylog_file:ssl-key.log \ 
-T fields -e frame.number -e _ws.col.Time -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport \
-e ip.dst -e tcp.dstport -e _ws.col.Protocol -e frame.len \
-e _ws.col.Info -E header=y -E separator="," -E quote=d \
-E occurrence=f -o tcp.desegment_tcp_streams:FALSE > segmented.csv
```

My intuition is that the resultant `disassembled.csv` file should be greater in size and should contain more rows given that the "packets above the MTU" will be shown as more than one packet.

However, I observe the opposite. The resultant file without assembly is smaller and has almost halved the number of rows.

```sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 210K May 18 18:21 desegmented.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  97K May 18 18:21 segmented.csv

# cat desegmented.csv |wc -l
2635
# cat segmented.csv |wc -l
1233
```

Is this a normal behavior? I don't see (manually) where the packets start to disappear (and why) or see any pattern because of the two-way communication (missing packets here and there).
I assume that *maybe*, in the `disassebmled.csv` case, every packet or even the whole packet stream that resulted in at least one packet above the MTU is completely dropped.

I tried to also apply ip.defragment:FALSE but still the same results.
Thanks

For reproducing, the files can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/etdlvnmwxb1vyha/AAAzofhTIBJI7CnWJ_JiQFBPa?dl=0)

Comment: Meanwhile, I have identified a couple of hundreds of TCP and TLS packets having a payload value of "TCP/TLS segment of a reassembled PDU" that are definitely removed from `disassembled.csv`.

Then, looking at the packet sizes in `disassembled.csv` I found the most packets having 4 digits of size, are missing, too (~200 packets). Still, I have many missing packets :S

Comment: I may be able to help, but you'd need to provide the files in your question (pcap/log files) so that others can replicate this (i.e. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). You may be running into a tshark behavior wherein it will spew info about the data into the text data output.

Comment: Added to the text, thanks.

Comment: I don't have a version of tshark built with TLS handy, so I wasn't able to replicate.  However, note that there is no IP fragmentation in the capture (a frame is an IP fragment if ip.flags.mf == 1 || ip.frag_offset > 0, which you can type into the filter in wireshark).  Your protocol stack is http2/TLS/TCP/IP/Ethernet II.  The "fragmentation" you are seeing is TLS records being split over multiple TCP frames. In order to decode TLS and see the http2, you will need to reassemble the TCP segments.  If you don't do so, you will only be able to decode the TLS records that fit in a single frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @JimD., I have already come to a similar conclusion!
Packet capture itself has to be segmented to do this precisely.

So, tried to go one layer below, and make the packet capture itself to be segmented via

```sh
ethtool -K eth0 gso off tso off gro off sg off tx off rx off
```

(just to make sure).

The problem is that packet capturing is done in a docker container, so at multiple places, I have to issue this command to be fully working.
These places include the `docker0` bridge, `eth0` inside the container and the corresponding `vethXXXXXX` on the host, from which the second requires privileged containers that pose further issues :)